# Mongodb find documents that match any criterion

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I'm writing a sinatra app that will serve as a backend for a service I'm building. Currently, I'm at a standstill as far as search is concerned.

I need to be able to do a MongoDB find query that matches documents if they match any of an array of criteria. Can MongoDB do anything like this? (ruby code):

```
results = @@mongodb["collection_name"].find( { "$any" => [ { "field" => keyword }, { "field2" => keyword } ] ).to_a
```

My thinking is based on the ruby function `Array.any?`.

Comment: You need to restructure your documents to be more MongoDB query friendly. You'll likely need a doc like: `key: 'keyname', value: 'thevalue'`. Then, you can search through any fields.

Answer (score 0):

[`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)?

```
{
  "$or" => [
    { "field" => keyword }, { "field2" => keyword }
  ]
}
```

Consider using [MongoMapper](http://mongomapper.com/) or [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html)

Comment: That will match any document where one of the fields is `keyword`. If both are `keyword`....

Comment: Mongoid looks promising, but I need it to be one query. Speed is of the essence.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a document you'd like to match and one you wouldn't?

Comment: It's more like I have a collection of docs and I want to match ones where any field is a specific value.

Comment: Oh, I see now. That's currently not possible with MongoDB. There is a ticket for that though: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. For now, I'm just doing 3 or 4 different MongoDB queries and aggressively optimizing them.